# Unable to locate repository containing directory during dotnet build or publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I am adding support for Docker on my ASP.NET Core 2.2 app and while testing the commands for docker locally I've found that the `dotnet publish -f netcoreapp2.2 -c Release -o out` errors out.

./IdentityServer.sln

```
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "IdentityServer", "IdentityServer\IdentityServer.csproj", "{A435DE31-3D1C-4228-BBD9-0157E849D07D}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Dependencies", "Dependencies", "{0A7E3F1D-5162-463F-BAF8-714C7FD37B8C}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "IdentityServer4", "dependencies\identityserver4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj", "{3A32B19C-B6FC-4A2D-9421-5A16849B7C2A}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity", "dependencies\identityserver4.aspnetidentity\src\IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity.csproj", "{0E36AE9A-B9B6-4E1C-B446-82A3265432F8}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "IdentityServer.Email", "IdentityServer.Email\IdentityServer.Email.csproj", "{BD699934-C404-4CF4-B77C-511E584D1754}"
EndProject
```

./IdentityServer/IdentityServer.csproj: https://gist.github.com/paulcsiki/4d3b827af418044dacea0149a2361b81

Output of `dotnet restore` on the same folder as the solution:

```
  Restore completed in 52.96 ms for /Users/paul/docker/dependencies/identityserver4.aspnetidentity/src/IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity.csproj.
  Restore completed in 52.96 ms for /Users/paul/docker/dependencies/identityserver4/src/IdentityServer4.csproj.
  Restore completed in 54.56 ms for /Users/paul/docker/IdentityServer/IdentityServer.csproj.
  Restore completed in 52.97 ms for /Users/paul/docker/IdentityServer.Email/IdentityServer.Email.csproj.
```

Output of the `dotnet publish -f netcoreapp2.2 -c Release -o out` on the same folder as the solution:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 44.29 ms for /Users/paul/docker/dependencies/identityserver4/src/IdentityServer4.csproj.
  Restore completed in 44.3 ms for /Users/paul/docker/IdentityServer.Email/IdentityServer.Email.csproj.
  Restore completed in 45.91 ms for /Users/paul/docker/IdentityServer/IdentityServer.csproj.
  Restore completed in 44.3 ms for /Users/paul/docker/dependencies/identityserver4.aspnetidentity/src/IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity.csproj.
/Users/paul/.nuget/packages/microsoft.build.tasks.git/1.0.0-beta-63127-02/build/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.targets(20,5): error : Unable to locate repository containing directory '/Users/paul/docker/dependencies/identityserver4/src'. [/Users/paul/docker/dependencies/identityserver4/src/IdentityServer4.csproj]
  IdentityServer.Email -> /Users/paul/docker/IdentityServer.Email/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/IdentityServer.Email.dll
  IdentityServer.Email -> /Users/paul/docker/IdentityServer.Email/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/IdentityServer.Email.Views.dll
  IdentityServer.Email -> /Users/paul/docker/IdentityServer.Email/out/
```

I've tried running the restore and publish command from the WebApp folder (/Users/paul/docker/IdentityServer) and it yields the same output.

Output of the `file /Users/paul/docker/dependencies/identityserver4/src/IdentityServer4.csproj`:

```
/Users/paul/docker/dependencies/identityserver4/src/IdentityServer4.csproj: exported SGML document text, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text
```

Comment: Verify the paths in /Users/paul/docker/dependencies/identityserver4.aspnetidentity/src/IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity.csproj. Also, try moving the complete solution outside of your user directory and for instance, store it in a folder like C:\projects\

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was that I have referenced a project called IdentityServer4 which had a reference to the Sourcelink NuGet package which was looking for the .git folder. Removing the package reference has resolved the issue.

Comment: PLease provide instructions !

Comment: Open the csproj file of the projects you have and remove the reference to the Sourcelink package.

Comment: I removed it from IdentityServer4.csproj. It worked. Thanks Paul.

Answer (score 8):

I can confirm @Paul solution. I edited the .csproj file and removed the package reference to `Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Remove following line: -->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub" Version="1.0.0-beta-62925-02" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```